# Weil Petersson metric on moduli space of Calabi Yau manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, singularity-theory, calabi-yau

Let $f:(X,D)\to Y$ be a holomorphic fibre space where $D$ is divisor with conic singularities and let fibres $(X_s,D_s)$ are log Calabi-Yau pair .i.e $K_X+D$ is nummerically trivial, then we have logarithmic Weil-Petersson metric on space of paired Calabi Yau fibers. Let show it with $\omega_{WP}^{D}$, then how can we compute the difference

$$\omega_{WP}^{D}-\omega_{WP}$$ on pair $(X,D)$.